# pandas: map multiple columns to one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns that I want to map to a single new column using the same dictionary (and return 0 if there is no matching key in the dictionary).

```
>> codes = {'2':1,
            '31':1,
            '88':9,
            '99':9}

>> df[['driver_action1','driver_action2']].to_dict()    
{'driver_action1': {0: '1',
  1: '1',
  2: '77',
  3: '77',
  4: '1',
  5: '4',
  6: '2',
  7: '1',
  8: '77',
  9: '99'},
 'driver_action2': {0: '31',
  1: '99',
  2: '31',
  3: '55',
  4: '1',
  5: '5',
  6: '99',
  7: '2',
  8: '4',
  9: '99'}}
```

I thought that I could just do:

```
>> df['driver_reckless_remapped'] = df[['driver_action1','driver_action2']].applymap(lambda x: codes.get(x,0))
```

Expected output:

```
  driver_action1 driver_action2   driver_reckless_remapped
0              1             31                          1
1              1             99                          9
2             77             31                          1
3             77             55                          0
4              1              1                          0
5              4              5                          0
6              2             99                          1
7              1              2                          1
8             77              4                          0
9             99             99                          9
```

But instead I get:

```
TypeError: ("'dict' object is not callable", 'occurred at index driver_action1')
```

Is there no way to map multiple columns to one new column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can use [combine_first()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method

```
df['new'] =  = \
    df.driver_action1.map(codes).combine_first(df.driver_action2.map(codes)).fillna(0)
```

Check:

```
In [106]: df['new'] = df.driver_action1.map(codes).combine_first(df.driver_action2.map(codes)).fillna(0)

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
  driver_action1 driver_action2 driver_reckless_remapped  new
0              1             31                        1  1.0
1              1             99                        9  9.0
2             77             31                        1  1.0
3             77             55                        0  0.0
4              1              1                        0  0.0
5              4              5                        0  0.0
6              2             99                        1  1.0
7              1              2                        1  1.0
8             77              4                        0  0.0
9             99             99                        9  9.0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using more than 2 columns... I added some more text to my post to clarify with an example of using 3 columns.

Comment: @ale19, this changed question invalidates my answer - could you please open a new question?

Comment: Will do. I also just revised my question so that it matches what you answered. New question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544989/pandas-map-more-than-2-columns-to-one-column