# How to lookup and bring in a value from another dataframe based on values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, vlookup

I have two dataframes. I need to bring a value from the right (second) database and add it as a column to the left (first) dataframe based on two other columns that exist in both dataframes. When doing so, I need to assign this column a different name in the left dataframe than what it is called in the right dataframe.

I ruled out `merge` and `join` because dataframes have hundreds of columns and I only need to bring over one column and I also need to change the column name when doing so. Instead I'm trying to `map` it.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
emp_data = {
            'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Steve', 'Steve'],
            'Age':[28,34,29,42], 
            'Job':['Engineer', 'Coordinator', 'Analyst', 'Manager']
            }

emps = pd.DataFrame(emp_data)
print(emps)

pay_data = {
            'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Steve', 'Steve'],
            'Age':[28,34,29,42], 
            'Salary':[80, 50, 70, 100]
            }

pay = pd.DataFrame(pay_data)
print(pay)

keys = ['Name', 'Age']
emps['Pay'] = emps[keys].map(pay.set_index(keys)['Salary'])
```

As a result I expect `emps` dataframe to have 4 columns: Name, Age, Job, and Pay. Column "Pay" will have the data from the column "Salary" in the `pay` dataframe and will be mapped based on Name and Age.

Instead the code gives me an error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

However, when I change the code to map based on one value (making the values unique first), the code works.

```
import pandas as pd
emp_data = {
            'Name':['Tom', 'Bill', 'Steve', 'John'],
            'Age':[28,34,29,42], 
            'Job':['Engineer', 'Coordinator', 'Analyst', 'Manager']
            }

emps = pd.DataFrame(emp_data)
print(emps)

pay_data = {
            'Name':['Tom', 'Bill', 'Steve', 'John'],
            'Age':[28,34,29,42], 
            'Salary':[80, 50, 70, 100]
            }

pay = pd.DataFrame(pay_data)
print(pay)


emps['Pay'] = emps['Name'].map(pay.set_index('Name')['Salary'])
print(emps)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age          Job  Pay
0    Tom   28     Engineer   80
1   Bill   34  Coordinator   50
2  Steve   29      Analyst   70
3   John   42      Manager  100
```

So, I'm trying to figure out what the real issue is and how to fix it.Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: @Erfan, The example I gave is just to give an idea. My real data frames have hundreds of columns. Merge brings over all the columns and keeps their names. I only need to bring over one out of hundreds and change its name in the process.

Comment: This is still a merge, just bring over the two columns you need. for example `emps.merge(pay[['pay', 'anothercolumn']], on=['Name', 'Age'])`

Comment: `emps.merge(pay[['Name', 'Age', 'Salary']], on=['Name', 'Age']).rename(columns={'Salary':'Pay'})`

Comment: How do i bring them over with a different name?

Comment: To rename use `df.rename({'Pay':'new name'}, axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: The reason I want to rename the column when bringing it over is because a column with that name already exists..

Comment: Merge and rename all in one step like Chris suggested worked for me. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your index has to be on two columns, you cannot use map. Instead you have to use merge as Erfan and It_is_Chris suggested.

The merge code that will work for this is:

```
emps.merge(pay[['Name', 'Age', 'Salary']], on=['Name', 'Age']).rename(columns={'Salary':'Pay'})
```

One other option is to use combine_first. However, there are some challenges with it as the combination does not result in a correct value. The best option still remain Merge.

If you want to try, you can look at [combine_first option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543634/pandas-map-multiple-columns-to-one-column)